# Creating t* array with adresses to t array fields

Tags: c++, arrays

Can the following code be shortened?

```cpp
size_t n_arr{4};
int arr[4]{1, 4, 5, 6};
int* arr_p[4];

for (; n_arr—; )
   arr_p[i] = &arr[i];
```

The adresses are all chained together, so is there a more efficient way of grabbing a block of adresses and storing them in another array?

Comment: Why do you need that? What's the advantage of storing addresses separately instead of calculating them on the fly when they are needed?

Comment: I can access one main array via separate arrays that are rotated. So, when I call `*arr_p[0]` it could for different rotations correlate to different positions on the main array. Useful for game board starting positions for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
#include <numeric>
...
std::iota(std::begin(arr_p), std::end(arr_p), arr);
```

where `std::iota` is typically used to generate a sequential range of integers, it's generic and so generates a sequential range of pointers starting from `arr` (which itself is short for `&arr[0]`).

More explicitly,

```
#include <algorithm>
...
std::transform(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), arr_p, [](int& x) { return &x; });
```

which takes each element by reference and populates `arr_p` with pointers to those elements.

https://godbolt.org/z/T8KGshn68

Comment: That's quite a trick. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you could write this:

```
size_t n_arr{4};
int arr[4]{1, 4, 5, 6};
int* arr_p[4];
int *narr_p;
int **arr_pp;

narr_p = arr;
arr_pp = arr_p;
for (; n_arr--; )
   *arr_pp++ = narr_p++;
```

But as Yksisarvinen wrote, having an array of sequential pointers does not seem very useful.

Edit: A slightly more elegant formulation (in my opinion):

```
size_t n_arr{4};
int arr[4]{1, 4, 5, 6};
int* arr_p[4];

for (int **arr_pp = arr_p, *narr_p = arr; n_arr--; )
   *arr_pp++ = narr_p++;
```

And a third one:

```
size_t n_arr{4};
int arr[4]{1, 4, 5, 6};
int* arr_p[4];

for (int **arr_pp = arr_p, *narr_p = arr; n_arr--; *arr_pp++ = narr_p++);
```

Comment: I don’t think I can get the new array from that, as it is now a pointer. But very nice idea, with the addition. In my case the best implementation would probably be `arr_p[n_arr] = arr++;`, I’d just have to change the for loop. Can you actually count up arrays, though?

Comment: You don't need to get the new array, the pointer is just a helper variable. The `arr_p` contains the pointers in the end.

Comment: Imagine `arr_p` is a book, `arr_pp` is just a bookmark showing you which position you are currently at.

Comment: Nevermind, the edit fixed it, thx

Comment: Yeah, sorry. In the assignment I forgot that you need an lvalue on the left hand side.